# Refresh parent node from backing bean with primefaces tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

Currently I am working on a project that use primefaces 3.4.1 version which does not support drag and drop in tree component. So I am using a contextMenu instead of drag and drop.

```
<p:tree id="treeHierarchy"
            value="#{hierarchyManagementBackingBean.root}" var="node"
            dynamic="true" selectionMode="single" cache="false"
            style="width:99%;" selection="#{hierarchyManagementBackingBean.selectedNode}">

            <p:treeNode id="idtreenode">
                <h:outputText value="#{node.name} (#{node.entityType})" />
            </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>


<p:contextMenu for="treeHierarchy">
            <p:menuitem value="Cut" actionListener="#{hierarchyManagementBackingBean.cutNode}"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Paste" actionListener="#{hierarchyManagementBackingBean.pasteNode}"/>
</p:contextMenu>
```

In backing bean,

```
public void cutNode() {
    ChildNodeDTO select = (ChildNodeDTO) selectedNode.getData();
    selectedNode.getParent().getChildren().remove(selectedNode);
    selectedNode.setParent(null);
    selectedNode = null;
}
```

Is there a way to refresh parent node from backing bean so that change can see on the tree?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a way to achieve this functionality.

```
<h:form id="frmHierachiManage" styleClass="treeForm">
-- tree inside this form
</h:form>
```

then in the backing bean,

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("frmHierachiManage");
```

this updated the tree view.

Comment: Great answer,  but it is what I also told you. Why not accept mine?

Comment: Yes I got it now, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only update the full tree afaik